# Textview not wrapping text inside list

Tags: android, textview

I want to show items on a `SearchView` using `SimpleCursorAdapter`. I have my code something like this:

```
    mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.my_text_view,
            null,
            new String[]{"cityName"},
            new int[] { android.R.id.text1},
            CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(this.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView sv = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.svBusqueda);
    sv.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    sv.setSuggestionsAdapter(mAdapter);
    sv.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    sv.setQueryHint("cityName");
```

And my text view layout used for the search items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:scrollHorizontally="false"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:maxLines="100"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall" />
```

The search Works perfectly, but for some reason I can't make the text to wrap in the `TextView`. ¿What am I missing?

Comment: Try to remove this line:  android:layout_weight="1"

Comment: nope, still does not wrap the text

Comment: try specifying the width like 200dp or something and check.

Comment: it smalls the textview, but the text get cutted and cant see the rest of the string. I even put lines="2" and it shows 2 lines but the text is shown only in the first line and not wrapped

Answer (score 1):

You must use 2 parameters :

```
android:ellipsize="none" : the text is not cut on textview width

android:scrollHorizontally="false" the text wraps on as many lines as necessary
```

Comment: you changed android:layout_width to 200dp?

Comment: yes, it smalls the textview, but the text get cutted and cant see the rest of the string. I even put lines="2" and it shows 2 lines but the text is shown only in the first line and not wrapped

Comment: change android:layout_width="0dp"

Comment: with 0dp the textview shows nothing. The problem comes when I want to display the textview in the SimpleCursorAdapter. In the textview android studio preview, the text wraps perfectly. When I show the textview inside the list it doesnt wrap

Comment: try adding your text view inside linear layout with android:orientation="horizontal" and textview width 0dp

Comment: I tried before, but the SimpleCursorAdapter does not recognize the textview in the my_text_view.xml